# How to get distinct count in excel from two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I have two columns as below:

[image]

Now if I want to get distinct count based on my multiple criteria, I tried to apply the formula below

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A7,"Arnold",B2:B7,"1"))
```

Now the result is `2` because `Arnold` matches twice with `Column B` with value `1`.

Now I need the output to be `1` based on distinct value in `column B`.

Comment: Do you want a unique count by class or name?

Comment: @ScottCraner: I need unique count based on class

Answer (score 0):

USE

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B7=1)/(COUNTIFS(A2:A7,A2:A7,B2:B7,1)+(B2:B7<>1)))
```